# How to calculate log likelihood for a model which outputs log probability?

Tags: regression, probability, likelihood

I am trying to compare some different models, some of them take samples and some of them make a single prediction. I have a reference here https://github.com/yaringal/ConcreteDropout/blob/master/concrete-dropout-keras.ipynb in the `Eval Function` box. I was using this, but I get some answers that don't make sense and I cannot justify why.

The link above calculates log probability like this...

$$
\frac{1}{N}[\log\sum_k\exp\Big(\sum_n \log p(y | x)\Big) - \log(K)]
$$

where $K$ is the number of samples taken, and you could view that as a division in exponential space or a subtraction in log space.

If I write this expression myself while I am coding I write it like this, but the answers come out different and as far as I can tell they are not equivalent expressions.

$$
\frac{1}{N}\sum_n[\log\sum_k\exp(\log p(y | x)) - log(K)]
$$

Which one is the correct way to write this?

Comment: There is no $y$ term in your second equation?

Comment: sorry that was a typo, fixed

Comment: Can you please add details about what $y$, $x$, $n$ and $k$ mean? Also when you are summing over $k$ and $n$ do you have the corresponding indices in the $y$ or $x$?

Comment: as I mentioned in the post, $k$ is the number of samples. $n$ would be the number of data points. $y$ and $x$ are just the data instances and labels